# SwiftUI View doesn't update in a seperate View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm using a `List` to display checkmarks of messages. The issue is if i seperate the checkmarks view into a subview that view doesn't get updated. If i put ***exactly the same code*** directly into the `List` it works as expected. I'm using that checkmarks view in multiple places so it need to be in a subview.

### Example:

This **doesn't** work:

```swift
List(filteredMessages, id: \.content.uniqueIdentifier) { message in
     DoubleCheckmark(message: message)
}
```

But this **does work**:

```swift
List(filteredMessages, id: \.content.uniqueIdentifier) { message in
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        if message.content.readStatus == .loading {
            Text("loading")
        } else if message.content.readStatus == .sent {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(message.content.readStatus == .read ? .blue : .gray)
        } else if message.content.readStatus == .received {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor( .gray)

            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding(.leading, -7)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        } else if message.content.readStatus == .read {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding(.leading, -7)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        } else {

            Text("error")
        }
    }
    .height(11)
    .width(15)
    .yOffset(-1)
}
```

This is my `DoubleCheckmark` view:

```swift
struct DoubleCheckmark: View {
    var message: Message

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            if message.content.readStatus == .loading {
                Text("loading")
            } else if message.content.readStatus == .sent {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundColor(message.content.readStatus == .read ? .blue : .gray)
            } else if message.content.readStatus == .received {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundColor( .gray)

                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding(.leading, -7)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else if message.content.readStatus == .read {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)

                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding(.leading, -7)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            } else {

                Text("error")
            }
        }
        .height(11)
        .width(15)
        .yOffset(-1)
    }
}
```

This is my `Message` class:

```swift
public class Message: NSObject, Codable, NSCoding {
    public var content: MessageContent
    public var fromUser: User
    public var toUser: User

    public init(content: MessageContent, fromUser: User, toUser: User) {
        self.content = content
        self.fromUser = fromUser
        self.toUser = toUser
    }

    enum Keys: String {
        case content, fromUser, toUser
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(content, forKey: Keys.content.rawValue)
        aCoder.encode(fromUser, forKey: Keys.fromUser.rawValue)
        aCoder.encode(toUser, forKey: Keys.toUser.rawValue)
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let content = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.content.rawValue) as! MessageContent
        let fromUser = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.fromUser.rawValue) as! User
        let toUser = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.toUser.rawValue) as! User

        self.init(content: content, fromUser: fromUser, toUser: toUser)
    }

    public override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? Message {
            return self.content.uniqueIdentifier == object.content.uniqueIdentifier
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `content.uniqueIdentifier` changed when `message.content.readStatus` changed? If not, then you `isEqual` does not work.

Comment: @Asperi of course its not changed as its a **uniqueIdentifier**

Comment: @Asperi do you have another idea?

Comment: I already wrote - your isEqual does not work, because for `readStatus` `.loading` and `.read` it returns *true*, but must *false*.

Comment: even if i explicitly return false it doesn't work @Asperi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my Message `class` to a `struct` and used `binary data` for the datatype in **CoreData** instead of **Transformable** which needs the model to conform to `NSCoding`

Answer (score 1):

If your `Message` is a class, then `List` most probably does not update rows for same messages due to equal references of `message` property. Try to conform your view to `Equatable` explicitly and override same in `Message` to make comparison deeply

```
struct DoubleCheckmark: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: DoubleCheckmark, rhs: DoubleCheckmark) -> Bool {
        lhs.message == rhs.message
    }
    ...
```

and

```
class Message: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
        // compare here all important properties
    }
    ...
```

alter this it might be also needed to mentioned explicitly that your custom view is custom equatable

```
List(filteredMessages, id: \.content.uniqueIdentifier) { message in
     DoubleCheckmark(message: message).equatable() // try with & w/o
}
```

Comment: Message need to be a class as it needs to conform to NSCoding so i can use it with CoreData's Transformable

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS, it is not a problem, then you need to override `isEqual`, because it is a `NSObject`.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I attached the Message class in the question above. Please have a look @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t update because Message is not ObservableObject. If you pass a class instance you need to add @ObservedObject to the view property. Otherwise, SwiftUI doesn’t know that there was a change.
Also, the class must either mark the properties that changing with @Published wrapper, or manually call objectWillChange.send()